# how to extend options of a jquery plugin with an array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I am writing a jQuery plugin. There are some default options and I can change them on HTML, but how can I change  an option if it consists of an array?

Here is the code in plugin:

```
(function($){    
    $.fn.extend({  
        aniTag: function(options) {     
            var defaults = {
                radius: 25,
                defaultradius: 0,
                enableTilt: true,
                tilt : 20,
                random : true, 
                randomMax : 25 ,
            };

            var colors = new Array('4AC7ED', 'FDC015', '9F78EC', 'F25C33');         

            var options = $.extend(defaults, options); 

            return this.each(function() {                
                var o = options;
                //some stuff
            });
        }
    });  
})(jQuery);
```

Here is the html usage:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.tags').aniTag({enableTilt: false});
    });
</script>
```

As you can see I can change `enableTilt` option. What I need to do is to change the values in the `color` array. Yes, I know I need to put that array in `defaults` var, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add your array of colors to your defaults like so

```
var defaults = {
    radius: 25,
    defaultradius: 0,
    enableTilt: true,
    tilt : 20,
    random : true, 
    randomMax : 25 ,
    colors: ['4AC7ED', 'FDC015', '9F78EC', 'F25C33']
};
```

Then you can overwrite them with

```
$('.tags').aniTag({enableTilt: false, colors: ['ffffff', '000000']});
```

---

**Fiddle Demo**:  http://jsfiddle.net/Beufe/1/

```
var defaults = {
    radius: 25,
    defaultradius: 0,
    enableTilt: true,
    tilt: 20,
    random: true,
    randomMax: 25,
    colors: ['4AC7ED', 'FDC015', '9F78EC', 'F25C33']
};

alert(defaults.colors.length);  // output: 4
alert('Default Value colors[0] = ' + defaults.colors[0]);  // output: 4AC7ED

var options = $.extend(defaults, {
    enableTilt: false,
    colors: ['ffffff', '000000']
});

alert(options.colors.length);  // Output: 2
alert('New Value colors[0] = ' + options.colors[0]);  // output: ffffff
```

---

Comment: i added the array your way. but it doesn't get any values from the array. not even default ones

Comment: defaults.colors[0] produces a result of 4AC7ED, changing it by passing a new array and using `.extend()` the array will product a value of ffffff.  Fiddle demo here http://jsfiddle.net/Beufe/

Comment: thank you very much for the extra info about jsfiddle. this was the first time i used it :)

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought you could do -

```
var newcolors = new Array('FFFFFF', '00FFFF', '9F78EC', 'F25C33');
```

then just pass your array into your plug-in via the options map -

```
$('.tags').aniTag({enableTilt: false,colorArray:newcolors});
```

If you define the array in your initial options as well ,

```
var defaults = { radius: 25, defaultradius: 0, enableTilt: true, tilt : 20, random : true, randomMax : 25 , colorArray:colors };
```

Then the extend function should just overwrite the initial array with the new one that has been passed in.

Comment: Are you referring to `options.colorArray` in your plugin when you are using the array? The docs for `extend` suggest it should work for arrays - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

Answer (score 0):

i think you mean you want to get the parameters from the html attributes?

```
<a data-param1="test" data-param2="test">test</a>
```

then you could do

```
$('a').data('param1') and $('a').data('param2')
```

to get them.