# Store jQuery plugin init settings for subsequent initializations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using a lightbox jQuery plugin that I'm needing to re-initialize in different contexts with different settings, and I'm wondering if there's a way to save a default set of settings, including options and callback functions-- say, in the form of a variable or array-- that I can later reference in subsequent initializations?

Thus, if possible, it would look something like this, initially:

```
$(.selector).plugin ({
     var defaults = {
        width: value,
        height: value,
        useCaption: value,
        onInit : {
            function()
        }
     }
});
```

And then re-invoke these defaults with additional options or overrides like so:

```
$(.selector).plugin ({
    defaults,
    additionalOption1: 'scroll',
    additionalOption2: true
});
```

Basically, I'd like to avoid having to re-state the same settings in different initialization-- is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like jQuery already is in use :)

```
var defaults={
    width: value,
    height: value,
    useCaption: value,
    onInit : {
        function()
    }
};

$(.selector).plugin(defaults);

$(.another-selector).plugin(
    $.extend({}, defaults, {
        additionalOption1: 'scroll',
        additionalOption2: true
    });
```

Comment: this is great, thanks-- I'll give it a try. One more question: if I specify, say, an initial `width` value in `defaults`, can I override the property by specifying a different `width` value in `$.extend` or only new values not first defined in `defaults`?

Comment: as an additional comment, I found my solution using @SergeRodovnichenko's answer and [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212991/how-to-extend-options-of-a-jquery-plugin-with-an-array). Thank you.